# Why are these sets reflexive, transitive, and/or symmetrical?

Tags: relations

**I.** $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4), (5, 5), (1,3), (3,4)\}$ is reflexive

**II.** $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)\}$ is reflexive, symmetrical, transitive

Why the **second** set is **symmetrical**, when we **don't** have, for example, $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$?

Why the **second** set is **transitive**, when we **don't** have, for example, $(1,3)$ and $(3, 4)$ and $(1, 4)$?

Comment: Just because it hasn't got every possible symmetry, doesn't mean it is not symmetric.

Comment: @Nij It doesn't have at least one symmetric what about all ... Look at the second one it doesn't have for example (1, 2) & (2, 1) but it is symmetrical, the first one also doesn't have the same pattern.

Comment: @Nij If we count (1,1) as symmetrical then why the first set is not symmetrical?

Comment: I don't think you understand what symmetric means, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry means that **if** the set contains $(a,b)$, then it must contain $(b,a)$ as well.  But that does not mean that it contains both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ ... it could also contain neither.

Put differently, the only way for a set to be not symmetric, is if it contains $(a,b)$ for some $a$ and $b$, but not $(b,a)$. This is not the case for the second set, so the second set is symmetric. The first set is not symmetric, since it contains $(1,3)$, but not $(3,1)$

Likewise, transitivity means that **if** the set contains $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$, then it contains $(a,c)$ as well. For a set not to be transitive it has to contain $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$, but not $(a,c)$ for some $a$, $b$, and $c$. Again, this is not the case for the second set, so the second set is transitive. But the first set is not transitive: it contains $(1,3)$ and $(3,4)$, but not $(1,4)$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it perfectly. I have edited my answer to remove the transitive from the first set, because I copied it wrongly.

Comment: @GeorgiPeev You are welcome! :)